# Ruby Sass Compatibility Error IBM857 and UTF-8

Tags: css, ruby, utf-8, sass

Suddenly this happend to me today for no reason. I could not fix yet.

Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: IBM857 and UTF-8

Here is the backtrace log...

```
C:\Users\Bertan\Desktop\işlergüçler\teona\custom>sass --watch sass/style.scss:css/style.css --trace
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.

C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/importers/filesystem.rb:87:in `index': incompatible character encodings: IBM857 and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)


from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/importers/filesystem.rb:87:in `remove_root'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/importers/filesystem.rb:146:in `find_real_file'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/importers/filesystem.rb:32:in `mtime'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_checker.rb:134:in `mtime'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_checker.rb:163:in `block in dependency_updated?'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_checker.rb:81:in `stylesheet_modified_since?'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_checker.rb:69:in `stylesheet_needs_update?'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:211:in `block in update_stylesheets'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in `each'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in `update_stylesheets'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:294:in `watch'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin.rb:109:in `method_missing'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:360:in `watch_or_update'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:51:in `process_result'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:52:in `parse'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:19:in `parse!'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/bin/sass:13:in `<top (required)>'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/sass:23:in `load'

from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/sass:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: please format the error log as code, so that appears more readable. See [this formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Is this a new project?  The directory name might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @cimmanon yes I just solved :) Thank you